# Search Active Directory by Comparing Two Attributes

Tags: active-directory

I want to search my Active Directory for all users that DO NOT match the following criteria:

First letter of login name matches first letter of first name.
Remainder of login name matches last name.

So, user John Smith with logon jsmith would be a match.  How can I query AD to find users who do not match this criteria?

Comment: do you have powershell available and the AD web service running?  Not completely necessary but does make things easier.

Comment: Powershell - yes.  I'm not sure about the AD web service.  I need to talk to the admin.  Even with powershell, what would the query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little PowerShell script that uses the Quest AD cmdlets, available [here](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).  It constructs the desired logon and then compares it to the current logon, writing out the invalid logon names to the console window.  You could have it output to a file or whatever.

```
$users = Get-QADUSer -SizeLimit 0

foreach ($user in $users)
{

$firstinitial = $user.FirstName.Substring(0,1)
$lastname = $user.LastName.ToString()
$compareterm = $firstinitial + $lastname
if ($compareterm -ne $user.LogonName)
    {
    Write-Host $compareterm "has an invalid logon name."
    }
}
```